# AspectJ pointcut to match methods annotated with @Test

Tags: java, testng, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am building a module that listens to TestNG tests and performs certain actions just before a test method starts its execution, for every test method. 
I just want to know when a test(method) starts its execution, name of the method and optionally name of the test class.

I was successfully able to write pointcuts for invoker calls of testNG. It worked.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* org.testng.internal.IInvoker.invokeTestMethods(..))")
```

Instead, I was wondering as every test method is annotated with `@org.testng.annotations.Test`, how can I write pointcut to catch execution joinPoint of every test method annotated with `@org.testng.annotations.Test`?

Here is how my test looks like

```
@BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
       //setup logic
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    private void configure() {
        //config logic
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoad() {
    //test
    }

    @Test
    public void testForm() {
    //test
    }
```

I tried a few pointcuts, they turned out to be invalid ones.
**Note:** I am using load time weaving.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
"execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.testng.annotations.Test)"
```